# Kinematics Help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration

A car passes a checkpoint on a road and then accelerates at $3\, m s^{-2}$ to another checkpoint $200\, m$ away. The speed of the car is $40 \,m s^{-1}$ when it passes the second checkpoint.

a) What is the car's speed at the first checkpoint?

b) What time does the car take to travel from one checkpoint to the next?

This is just a classroom question which I always seem to get stuck on. An answer with a detailed explanation would be amazing. Thanks!

External forces like air resistance etc. are ignored.
$g = 9.8 \, ms^{-2}$

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck on? You should show some effort, and you won't probably receive a detailed answer, try to write down a sketch of a solution and we'll help you. I won't give you the solution but if you are more precise in what you aren't able to do i'd gladly help.

Comment: I've just attempted this again. I used v^2 = u + 2as (equation of motion) with the v being 40, u being 0, a is 3 and s is 200. Then I found U (initial velocity) being 20ms. Then answering part b, I used d = vt with d being 200, v being 20. then found t to be 10s. Is this correct because I highly doubt myself.

Comment: First, check the edit I've made to your question, write numbers and units putting a dollar symbol before and after, it would be easy for us to read. What is $u$? a velocity? you need a squared velocity in that formula. and $u$ isn't zero, $u$ is what you're looking for. $v^2 = u^2 + 2 as$, where $v$ is the speed at the **second** checkpoint, and $u$ is the speed at the **first** one, but you calculated it right since you found $20 m/s$, so I think you just mistyped the comment. For the second part you can't use that formula, cause you have an accelerated motion... Hope this help

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for “check my work” problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic). You might get a better response at a more appropriate site.  [Here’s one to consider.](http://www.physicsforums.com), but there are others.

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You might it easier to sketch a velocity time graph for this motion and label the known (acceleration, distance travelled before reaching the final speed and final speed) and unknown quantities (initial speed and time taken to reach final speed).
The gradient of the graph is the acceleration and the area under the graph is the distance travelled.
You can then set up two equations with the two unknowns.